# Exceptions on iostreams

Tags: c++, exception, iostream

I have recently learned that one can opt-in into exceptions for iostreams. In order to not have to check manually if a file is open I tried that and ran into this behaviour:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

void test(std::istream& is, bool exceptions) {
  try {
    if (exceptions)
      is.exceptions(std::istream::failbit);
    std::vector<int> input;
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>{is}, {}, std::back_inserter(input));
    for (auto x : input) {
      std::cout << x << '\n';
    }
  }
  catch (const std::ios_base::failure& f) {
    std::cerr << "Caught error: " << f.what() << '\n';
  }
}

int main() {
  // Emulates file
  std::stringstream ss("1 2 3\n4 5 6\n7 8 9\n");
  test(ss, true);
}
```

When exceptions are set off this works normally. But when I use exceptions I get one thrown from `basic_ios::clear` and I can't think of a reason why.

`basic_ios::clear` is not listed under the function that can set the `failbit` according to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate).

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** The answers below already answer why this happens. My additional question now is how to avoid this exception? My second attempt was to replace `std::copy` by this loop:

```
for (int n; is >> n;) {
  input.push_back(n);
}
```

produced the same exception. Or is this behavior even intended?

**Note:** clang doesn't show this behavior.

Comment: `basic_ios::clear` is the lowest-level entry that sets iostate. Other functions set failbit/badbit/eofbit by calling `basic_ios::clear`.

Comment: @cpplearner: Thanks for making that clear. I still don't know why the above snippet throws any exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jonesinator has given you the reason of the exception, I would like just to stress that the error is there independently from the exception or not. In fact your function is not equivalent, you do not check the stream after the operation in the no-exception branch. In fact, an error silently happen. If you write the two functions in an equivalent way you will get the an equivalent result:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

void test_exception(std::istream& is) {
  try {
    is.exceptions(std::istream::failbit);
    std::vector<int> input;
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>{is}, {}, std::back_inserter(input));
    for (auto x : input) {
      std::cout << x << '\n';
    }
  }
  catch (const std::ios_base::failure& f) {
    std::cout << "Caught error: " << f.what() << '\n';
  }
}

void test_error_code(std::istream& is) {    
    std::vector<int> input;
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>{is}, {}, std::back_inserter(input));
    if (!is.good()) {
      std::cout << "Caught error!" << std::endl;
      return;
    }
    for (auto x : input) {
      std::cout << x << '\n';
    }     
}

int main() {
  // Emulates file
  std::stringstream ss_error_code("1 2 3\n4 5 6\n7 8 9\n");
  test_error_code(ss_error_code);

  std::stringstream ss_exception("1 2 3\n4 5 6\n7 8 9\n");
  test_exception(ss_exception);
}
```

**output:**

Caught error!

Caught error: basic_ios::clear

IMHO, this is a great example why exceptions are superior over result code in the vast majority of the scenario and they should be used as default.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The only thing I still don't understand is why the exception is thrown in the first place. I thought using iterators with algorithms should be the idiomatic way of reading the file. 
Do you know of a way to modify the code in order to not get those exceptions or error codes other than using raw loops?

Comment: @user4990485 Failbit will be set with eofbit if EOF is reached during input. So just set the badbit of the exception mask but do not set failbit nor eofbit. This code does not show a practice to follow.

Comment: @Oliv: Thanks for your explanation. Sadly `badbit` isn't set when a file couldn't be opened so I will have to check that manually which is what I wanted to avoid...

Comment: Indeed! The I/O stream error reporting mechanism is realy too scarse. The I/O stream library deserves a new implementation. I have read that the C++ standard commitee is actualy working on enhancing it.

Answer (score 4):

Using GDB you can see the error happens when the `std::istream_iterator` is incremented.

```
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
#1  0x00007ffff71d13fa in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89
#2  0x00007ffff7ae80ad in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x00007ffff7ae6066 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0x00007ffff7ae60b1 in std::terminate() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x00007ffff7ae62c9 in __cxa_throw () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x00007ffff7b0eea3 in std::__throw_ios_failure(char const*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#7  0x00007ffff7b4a82d in std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >::clear(std::_Ios_Iostate) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#8  0x00007ffff7b4d52f in std::istream::operator>>(int&) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#9  0x00005555555556c2 in std::istream_iterator<int, char, std::char_traits<char>, long>::_M_read (this=0x7fffffffe230) at /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stream_iterator.h:121
#10 0x0000555555555ac2 in std::istream_iterator<int, char, std::char_traits<char>, long>::operator++ (this=0x7fffffffe230) at /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stream_iterator.h:95
#11 0x0000555555555a36 in std::__copy_move<false, false, std::input_iterator_tag>::__copy_m<std::istream_iterator<int, char, std::char_traits<char>, long>, std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > > (__first=..., __last=..., __result=...) at /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_algobase.h:293
#12 0x0000555555555965 in std::__copy_move_a<false, std::istream_iterator<int, char, std::char_traits<char>, long>, std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > > (__first=..., __last=..., __result=...) at /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_algobase.h:386
#13 0x00005555555557e2 in std::__copy_move_a2<false, std::istream_iterator<int, char, std::char_traits<char>, long>, std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > > (__first=..., __last=..., __result=...) at /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_algobase.h:424
#14 0x00005555555554c9 in std::copy<std::istream_iterator<int, char, std::char_traits<char>, long>, std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > > (__first=..., __last=..., __result=...) at /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_algobase.h:456
#15 0x00005555555550ed in test (is=..., exceptions=true) at sample.cpp:12
#16 0x000055555555521c in main () at sample.cpp:25
```

Unrolling the loop, you can find that it is the last call to increment that causes the problem, i.e. calling `std::istream_iterator::operator++` when the input stream is empty.

Looking closer at the stack trace, the final increment is trying std::istream::operator>> when the stream is empty. According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2), that will result in the failbit being set since the operation failed to extract an integer from the stream.